# matrix transposition in multiplication, eigen vs mkl

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen, matrix-multiplication, intel-mkl

In the dense and sparse module of mkl I can transpose or conjugate a matrix in the same function that calls the multiplication.

I think (but I'm not sure) that means that it's just changing the algorithm used to pick the elements inside the matrix itself (I like arrays, so i think the structure, internally, is array-like with an algorithm to define the order. But I may be wrong).

This way there is only the cache issue of picking elements not saved sequentially. However it's an operation far less time-consuming, than picking all the elements of the matrix and saving them in another one (even far less memory consuming).

So i was just wondering if there was a built-in way to implement this for the matrix multiplication of sparse and dense matrices in eigen.

Or just a way to "view" the matrix as the transpose or conjugate without any memory manipulation.

Comment: Re: "Or just a way to "view" the matrix as the transpose or conjugate without any memory manipulation" -- this is exactly what Eigen does.

Comment: If we use `double` for matrix4x4 it's require memory at least 8 * 4 * 4 = 128 bytes. assume we use 20 matrices per operation. it still is not so much compare with modern hardware. so it's unnecessary to concern about memory space for matrices. just copy them.

Comment: @JakkapongRattananen my usecase is 2GB sparse marices. Please don't assume what I'm doing

Comment: @chtz is there any documentation which states that? I would appreciate (no sarcasm involved). In the documentation I see that transposition require an output matrix which is different from the input matrix and if they are the same the memory allocation would affect the output, as the operation is still incomplete. This leads me to think that it's not just a change in the algorithm used when using the marix for other operations. That would not require an output matrix and it would just require 0 time

Comment: @manne Documentation of Eigen internals is not perfect. Here is something about the idea of ETs: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Expression_templates (also check the links). And if you check the docu for things like [`.transpose()`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a43cbcd866a0737eb56642c2e992f0afd) you (most of the time) see words like "expression of".

Comment: @chtz Do you mean transposeInPlace? it says something that seems right. So are you sure there is no memory reallocation, just an algorithm change, if the matrix is square?

Comment: I linked to and I meant `.transpose()`. This returns an "an expression of the transpose of *this", i.e., just a "view" of the transposed matrix. You will see that if you take a large matrix `A` and do `A.transpose()` without assigning the result to a matrix, no work at all is done. You can even do `A.transpose()(row,col)` and check that this equals `A(col,row)`. `.transposeInPlace()` will actually transpose the matrix, which even if it does not allocate memory takes time.

Comment: I think you have some fundamental misunderstanding about how Eigen works. You may want to check [expression templates on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates)

Comment: [This page](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixArithmetic.html) explicitly reads "As for basic arithmetic operators, `transpose()` and `adjoint()` simply return a proxy object without doing the actual transposition" and then later "for BLAS users worried about performance, expressions such as `c.noalias() -= 2 * a.adjoint() * b;` are fully optimized and trigger a single gemm-like function call."

Comment: thanks all. I needed some infos like that. Didn't notice how eigen worked for this operations